# Как сделать отрисовку элементов View в цикле?

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. В цикле нужно создавать элементы TextView и вкладывать их в linearLayout последовательно, через определенный промежуток времени. Проблема в том, что в цикле, хоть элементы и добавляются в существующую разметку, но рисоваться они начинают только прохода всей программы до конца. Как сделать так, чтобы элемент начинал отрисовыватся в конце итерации цикла. Пробовал уже использовать функции invalidate(), requestlayout(), forceLayout() в конце итерации, ничего не выходило.

```
protected void getStringForGame(){ 
if(stage==null) 
  stage = new String("start"); 
int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(stage, "array", 
this.getPackageName()); 
String[] s = getResources().getStringArray(id); 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
layoutParams.setMargins(0,50,0,50); 

for(int i = 0; i<s.length;i++){ 
    CustomTextView customTextView = new CustomTextView(this); 
    customTextView.setText(s[i]); 
    customTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
    mainLayout.addView(customTextView); 
    //customTextView.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(3000); 

} 
CreateAnswer answer = new CreateAnswer(); 
getMainLayout().addView(answer.crAnswer(this)); 
}
```

Может кто сталкивался с таким, очень нужен дельный совет.

Comment: скорее всего проблема в том, что всё происходит на UI потоке

Comment: UI поток рисует всё на экран, поэтому если загружать его другими задачами, он не сможет перейти к отрисовке до тех пор, пока не выполнит задачи, которыми вы его нагрузили.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496114/drawing-to-canvas-while-in-loop

Comment: Есть анимация, которая реализует появление экземпляра класса. Может подойдет: https://annimon.com/article/468

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у Вас в коде нигде не видно, чтобы устанавливалась хоть какая-то задержка между вызовами `addView` (помимо создания новых объектов, что происходит очень быстро). Так что считайте, что всё и так случается одновременно.

Во-вторых, раз уж Вам всё равно придётся работать в UI потоке, чтобы добавить новые вьюхи, воспользуйтесь методами класса `Handler`. Например, вот так:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CustomTextView customTextView = new CustomTextView(this); 
            customTextView.setText(s[i]); 
            customTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
            mainLayout.addView(customTextView);
        }
    }, TIME_DELAY_BETWEEN_ADDITIONS_IN_MS * i);
}
```

Код выше выполнит `Runnable`, добавляющий вьюху, `s.length` раз с задержкой `TIME_DELAY_BETWEEN_ADDITIONS_IN_MS` (в миллисекундах) между появлением каждого нового элемента. В качестве альтернативы можно использовать метод `Handler.postAtTime`, но это по сути другой способ сделать то же самое.

Кстати, необязательно играть какаю-то анимацию с помощью `animate()` после добавления элемента в контейнер, просто добавьте в XML-разметке атрибут `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` вашему `mainLayout` и новые элементы будут появляется с анимацией.

Comment: Спасибо, смог разобраться, по поводу того, что не было видно, что задержка устанавливается, то я почистил эти строки, так, был простой счетчик после добавления вью элемента в разметку. Не писал бы это, если бы уже не сделал. А ошибка была моя проста, все пытался сделать в основном потоке.